# regex search fails to terminate

Tags: python, regex

I am searching for motifs in sequences (which have gaps, that's why the regular expression looks overcomplex with a -* after each symbol in pattern).
The following code doesn't stop executing

```
import re
line = """MRVKE---TRKNY-QH--------S-----W-------GRGLWSLWRW-------------G---T-------MLLG--ML-M----IS-S--A-A-----E-Q---S--WVTVYYGVPVWREATT-TLFCASDAKAYDTEKH-NVWATHACVPTDPNPQEVQL--NVTENFNMWKNNMVDQMHEDIISLWDQSLKPCVQLTPLCVT-LNC-SD------TINA---TTANNTINA----------------TTT-----TPT-----I----NATT-------------ANKSMEIG---------E---MR----NCSFNIT----NM---G-K-KMK--EYALFYN----LDVV---------------SI-----------------D-------E-----------------DNNNK-------------------------------------------TS--------Y---RLK-SCNTSVI-TQACP-KVSFKPIPIHYCAPAGFAILKCND-KKFNGTGPCGNVSTVQCTHGIKPVVSTQLLLNGSLAE-E-EVVIRSENFTNNVKTIIVQLKNPVMINCTRP-NNNTR-KS-I---HM---GP----GQ-A-F-YAT-GAI---IGDIR-QAHCNI--SE-------------------------------------------K--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------E"""
pattern = "[KR]?-*[KR]?-*[KR]-*[^-]?-*[^-]?-*[KR]-*[^-]-*[^-]-*[^-]?-*[^-]?-*[ILVM]-*[^-]-*[ILVF]"

o = re.search(pattern, line)
```

The code works (that is finishes execution in microseconds) for other lines and for other motifs, e.g. the following ones:

```
pattern = "[KR]?-*[KR]?-*[KR]-*[^-]?-*[^-]?-*[KR]-*[^-]-*[^-]-*[^-]?-*[^-]?-*[ILVM]-*[^-]-*"
pattern = "[KR]-*[^-]?-*[^-]?-*[KR]-*[^-]-*[^-]-*[^-]?-*[^-]?-*[ILVM]-*[^-]-*[ILVF]"
```

If the large gap is removed from the end of the line it also works fine.
As a matter of fact vim also fails to finish execution for the particular this regex search.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like this is one of those REs that take super-linear time in [naive RE matchers, such as Python's](http://swtch.com/~rsc/regexp/regexp1.html). You can speed the first pattern up dramatically by rewriting it as something like

```
r"(?:[KR]-*){1,3}(?:[^-]?-*){2}[KR]-*(?:[^-]-*){2}(?:[^-]?-*){2}[ILVM]-*[^-]-*[ILVF]"
```

where `(?:` introduces a non-capturing group.

**EDIT**: the above RE is not entirely equivalent to yours; please correct it. The spirit of it is: use the `{m,n}` operation for repetition, since it causes less backtracking.

Comment: This isn't equivalent to his regex. For example, the `[KR]`s are optional the first two times...

Comment: @TimPietzcker: that's why there's a `{1,3}` after the group.

Comment: That doesn't work the same way, though. `--K-` is matched by `[KR]?-*[KR]?-*[KR]-*`, but not by `(?:[KR]-*){1,3}`.

Comment: @Abhijit: because constructs like `x?x?x`, where `x` is any RE, may cause the matcher to backtrack. By contrast, the equivalent `x{1,3}` can be matched deterministically. Check out the link I posted for some of the automata theory behind this.

Comment: Thx, it seems this regex does the trick for me:
    `(?:[KR]-*){1,3}(?:[^-]-*){0,2}[KR]-*(?:[^-]-*){2,4}[ILVM]-*[^-]-*[ILVF]`